# Use sign up info in customers account area in WordPress?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

When readers sign up for a account in our wordpress site. My team wants to use their first name they signed up with, to say Hi [firstname] welcome back!

Of course with having readers already I want their accounts to show that too. Could there be a short code or html to add?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this from functions.php

```
function welcome_message_to_users() {
global $current_user;
get_currentuserinfo();
if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
    echo '<p>Welcome' . $current_user->display_name . '</p>';
}
```

}
add_filter( 'wp_head', 'welcome_message_to_users' );

Comment: Great that worked like a charm! Is there a chance I could do this in a post/page also? When readers sign up they have a sign up field to input who referred them. In there account page we just want to put "you were refereed by [referral name]!" is that possible with this same function? Thanks!

Comment: Yes. You can try using `if ( is_user_logged_in && is_page ( ID of the page ) ) {echo 'tralala'}`. For more information about the conditional tag is_page you can access this: [link](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_page). For the referal name i don't think I can help you because it depends a lot on how you add it in the first place.